# SQL Query help for single table query

Tags: sql

I have a table that records status on course progress. A new record is added for each user/course comination when a course is started. That record is updated with a 'completed' status when the course is completed. I need to find the records for users who have never completed any courses.

Example Table:

```
User  Course  Status
A      1       S
A      2       C
B      1       S
C      2       S
D      2       C
C      3       S
```

I need a query that finds the following:

```
User  Course  Status
B      1        S
C      2        S
C      3        S
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
select user, course, status
from your_table
where user in 
(
    select user
    from your_table
    group by user
    having sum(CASE WHEN status = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
)
```

Comment: +1 For some RDBMS you will need to use `CASE` in the sum  `HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0`, if the RDBMS does not return a 1 for a boolean comparison (like MySQL does)

Comment: Can you select 3 columns and group by 1?  I'm a MS-flavoured SQL programmer, and I can't in the SQL I use!

Comment: @sebt That is an unfortunate default behavior of MySQL.  You can omit cols from the `GROUP BY` but the results you get back may end up being non-deterministic for those columns.

Comment: @sebt: I already updated my answer a few minutes back. Please try it.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: I did not know that; thanks!  I'd call it "unfortunate" as well; I can imagine not thinking too clearly about aggregations (I've often been there...experience just means it happens _less often_ now), writing code like that, getting no error, but getting non-determistic results.  And perhaps not noticing.  [shudder]

Comment: @juergend: that works!  I think the WHERE status<>'C' in the outer query can be dropped, as the user will (by the IN clause) inevitably have no "C" rows.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select User, Course, Status from MyTable where User not in (Select Distinct User from MyTable where Status = 'C')
```

Comment: +1 Same logic as my answer.  I have a (possibly inexplicable) aversion to IN when I can use a join... the optimiser quite possibly treats both the same way...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT User,Course,Status FROM YourTable a
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT User FROM YourTable WHERE Status='C') CompletedAnything
ON a.User=CompletedAnything.User
WHERE COmpletedAnything.User IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a SQL Fiddle that gives you what you want:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b6988/1

Query is this:

```
select User, Course, Status
from mytable
where User not in 
  (select distinct User from mytable where status = 'C' ans User is not null)
```